# React js Moment Timezone has no data for IST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console, moment-timezone

I have used moment-timezone in my react js project. date time conversion is showing correctly but **Moment Timezone has no data for IST** error is showing in console

```
import moment from "moment-timezone";

export function utcToDate() {
const zone_name = moment.tz.guess();
const timezone = moment.tz(zone_name).zoneName();
return moment(1607954125191).tz(timezone).format("MMM DD YYYY, hh:mm A"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use zone_name instead of timezone

```
return moment(date).tz(zone_name).format("MMM DD YYYY, hh:mm A");
```